# Display image from the blob using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have an preview button for my image, what I want to do is when user hover, it shows the preview of image.

The images are saved in a blob. And my query is working fine because when I output Image I see long unformatted text string.

**Here is my jQuery**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.stock-image-hover',function(){
    var imageid = $(this).attr('image-id');
    var image = $(this).attr('image');
    var imageView='<img src="data:image/png;base64,'+image+ ' />'";
    console.log(imageid);
});
```

Var **Imageid** just gets the IF of THE image.
var **image** gets the image from blob (long unformatted text strong with lots of symbols and characters)

var **imageView** should render the image in image base.

I am struggling with the third variable as it's not rendering the image.

Many Thanks

Comment: Can you post `html` sample?

Comment: I think you've mixed up your quotation marks - ' />'"; should be '"/>'; https://jsfiddle.net/vxw6qw42/